# React/TypeScript Library with tsup: 'useState' TypeError in Next.js App

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, esbuild, tsup

I've been working on a React-based component library and I'm encountering an issue when trying to integrate it into a Next.js application. I'm hoping someone here might have insights or suggestions on how to resolve this. Here's the breakdown of my setup and the problem I'm facing …

I aim to build a small React-based package using `tsup` that can be installed and used in a Next.js app.

I've configured `tsup` successfully and it produces an ESM build of my library. The library functions perfectly (sort of) and has been tested within a Storybook environment.

After installing the library into my Next.js app and attempting to import it, I encounter the following runtime error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
```

This error suggests an issue with React's `useState` hook, but it's unclear why this is happening, especially since the library works flawlessly in Storybook. Printing `{React.version}` in the component works fine, for some reason whereas `useEffect` causes the same error as useState.

#### Steps to Reproduce:

For anyone willing to take a closer look, you can find a minimal reproducible example and steps how to reproduce the issue here: [wiremore/library-issue](https://github.com/wiremore/library-issue)

Any insights into why this error might be occurring or how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated. I'm curious if it's related to the way `tsup` is building the package or a specific consideration I might have missed for Next.js.

Thanks in advance for your help!